# jQuery: fire mouseleave only on sibling navbar-item

Tags: jquery

In the following jQuery code, currently the `mouseleave` evt fires when the mouse leaves the current evt target, however I want the mouseleave to fire only when the mouse is over any the sibling `.navbar-item` or mouse is outside the `.wrapper`, else not otherwise.

Not sure, how to code the logic, so can anybuddy help me solve this.

Here is the [CodePen demo](https://codepen.io/rseni/pen/VwmmmJK)

Thanks

```js
$('.second-lvl .navbar-item').mouseenter(function(){
    let id = $(this).attr('data-target')
    $('#'+id).show(500);
}).mouseleave(function(){
  let id = $(this).attr('data-target')
    $('#'+id).hide(0);
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  margin: 40px;
  background: lightblue;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
}
.navbar-item, .preview {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: #ececec;
  cursor: pointer; }

.preview {
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100px;
  top: 100px;
  display: none;
}
.visible {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="navbar-dropdown second-lvl">
    <div class="navbar-item" data-target="oak-1">
      <a>Oak 1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-item" data-target="oak-2">
      <a>Oak 2</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-item" data-target="oak-3">
      <a>Oak 3</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-item" data-target="oak-4">
      <a>Oak 4</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="all-previews">
    <div class="preview" id="oak-1">
      Oak Tree 1 info
    </div>

    <div class="preview" id="oak-2">
      Oak Tree 2 info
    </div>

    <div class="preview" id="oak-3">
      Oak Tree 3 info
    </div>

    <div class="preview" id="oak-4">
      Oak Tree 4 info
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `I want the mouseleave to fire only when the mouse is over any the sibling .navbar-item` is not clear,, do you want the mouseleave fires when leaving navbar-item?

Comment: and i dont understant your logic,is it: when you enter on navbar-item, you show the preview id, and hide when you quit the navbar-item?

Comment: @Frenchy Yes, currently the logic is when mouse is over `.navbar-item` it will show the target id div (the value in navbar-item attribute `data-target`) and when mouseleaves that item, the target id is hidden. Now what I want is to show the target id when mouseenter navbar-item but hide the target id only when mouseenters another sibling `.navbar-item` or outside `.wrapper` area else the target id is kept visible. Hope it's clearer to you. Can you help modify the code for this?

Answer (score 0):

If i have inderstood your logic, try that:

```js
var id='';
$('.second-lvl .navbar-item').mouseenter(function(){
    if(id == ''){
        id = $(this).attr('data-target')
        $('#'+id).show(500);
    }else{
        $('#'+id).hide(0);
        id = $(this).attr('data-target')
        $('#'+id).show(500);   
    }
})

$('.wrapper').mouseleave(function(){
        $('#'+id).hide(0);
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  margin: 40px;
  background: lightblue;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
}
.navbar-item, .preview {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: #ececec;
  cursor: pointer; }

.preview {
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100px;
  top: 100px;
  display: none;
}
.visible {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="navbar-dropdown second-lvl">
    <div class="navbar-item" data-target="oak-1">
      <a>Oak 1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-item" data-target="oak-2">
      <a>Oak 2</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-item" data-target="oak-3">
      <a>Oak 3</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-item" data-target="oak-4">
      <a>Oak 4</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="all-previews">
    <div class="preview" id="oak-1">
      Oak Tree 1 info
    </div>

    <div class="preview" id="oak-2">
      Oak Tree 2 info
    </div>

    <div class="preview" id="oak-3">
      Oak Tree 3 info
    </div>

    <div class="preview" id="oak-4">
      Oak Tree 4 info
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

you could write too this code:

```
$('.second-lvl .navbar-item').mouseenter(function(){
        $(".all-previews div[id^=oak]").hide(0);
        let id = $(this).attr('data-target')
        $('#'+id).show(500); 
});

$('.wrapper').mouseleave(function(){
        $(".all-previews div[id^=oak]").hide(0);
});
```